# How to toggle Stage3D between Fullscreen and Standard-screen mode?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, toggle, fullscreen, stage3d

I'm testing a few things with the ND2D library (made by [NullDesign](http://www.nulldesign.de/%20NullDesign), engine's source available at [github](https://github.com/nulldesign/nd2d)).

What I've encountered, is that if I toggle my Flash application to Fullscreen mode, the `World2D` (or `Stage3D` / `Context3D` buried inside it) doesn't auto-stretch to maximize it to the entire screen resolution.

Do I need to reinitialize my setup to the new Fullscreen dimensions? What if the `stage.scaleMode` is set to `"NO_SCALE"`? Will that affect the dimensions since the stage, although appearing larger, will still retain the same coordinate system and dimensions?

If anyone has ever figured out how to correctly toggle Fullscreen mode in `Stage3D`, please shed some light!

**Even better if you have a solution in ND2D :)**

Thanks!

Comment: This might be useful to those making fullscreen applications exclusively in Stage3D: http://pastebin.com/7DxKTxkz . But if you're mixing `DisplayObjects` (`Sprites`, `MovieClips`, `TextFields`, `Bitmaps`) you will notice the coordinate-system is a bit messed up with Mouse movements due to the `Stage`'s scaleMode.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @annonymously, I was able to come up with my own answer.
I've written up a post on my blog on how I achieved Fullscreen in Stage3D with ND2D.

See this post for details: http://pierrechamberlain.ca/blog/2011/12/as3-level-3-toggle-stage3d-fullscreen

First, I've looked through the ND2D forum thread mentioned by annonymously http://nulldesign.de/nd2d/forum/topic.php?id=10 and the most recent reply linked to an ND2D class extension for `World2D`, made by **Rolpege** (no idea who he is, but gracias!).

I modified it a bit so it does only what I need (it originally performed a few other tasks that I assume was presets / tailored to the developers' needs)

Although the example in the post contains quite a bit of *black-boxed* code (classes from my own personal library), I hope it will be useful for other Flash Developers to go over.